# How to expand root partition?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, resize

I tried some solutions and I saw it didn't work for me. I think I had another problem.
Can someone show me how to expand it?

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[image]

Comment: It's much easier if you tell us which solutions you tries so that we don't have to guess or rely on telekinsis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift /dev/sda5 to the right, so the unallocated space will be next to /dev/sda9. Then you can resize /dev/sda9.

EDIT: CARE! This will take time, and you can't abort it. For such a small space however it should be ok.

EDIT2: In case it's not obvious enough, you shift it by grabbing the box and pulling it to the right.

Comment: Thank for your help! Will this lose my data in /dev/sda9 ?

Comment: No it should not. However to be on the safe side you should make a backup. It destroyed my partition once.
EDIT: Also note you'll need to do this from your Live Disk.

Answer (score 0):

First, before you do anything else, there is always a small chance you will loose data, so back up your data.

The free (unallocated) space must be right next to (adjacent / touching) the partition you wish to expand.

You have a lot of partitions in a somewhat chaotic sequence, thus the free space is not adjacent to the partition you wish to enlarge.

So you must move the partitions and free space. This must be done in steps.

It appears you wish to expand sda9 ? and there is a small NFTS partitoin between sda9 and the free space so ...

1. Delete or move the NTFS partition (? sda5 )-> apply changes

now the free space and sda9 are next to each other so

2. Enlarge sda7 -> apply changes.

I would suggest you simplify your partitioning scheme and re-order your partitions, but that will take time and there is always some risk of data loss.

Comment: Thank you for you help.
I'm new to Ubuntu and i don't know how to simplify my partitioning scheme or what is the best order of these.
Can you give some advices?

Comment: Size and ordering of your partitions takes planning and is OS independent. Your first step is to decide how many and what size partitions you need. There is no single way to do this. Cleaning up your disk is unnecessary, but the disorder created  by your current partitioning scheme makes moving / resizing partitions difficult and multi step.